# The store schema does not contain the Element class SqlXmlCompressionOption

Tags: sql-server, azure, bacpac

I hope you are all good

I am doing or importing a bacpac file from azure SQL  to  SQL on-premisse
with  SSMS

and I am receiving this error.

Somebody get me help or give me a north

[image]

Details
Could not load schema model from package. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac)

---

Program Location:

at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DacPackage.LoadModel(IPackageSource packageSource, Boolean ignoreUnresolvedExternalErrors)
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.Extensions.DacExtensions.GetCollationString(IPackageSource packageSource)
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.Extensions.DacExtensions.GetCollationString(BacPackage package)
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Dac.DacWizard.CreateDatabaseOnTargetWorkItem.DoWork()
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.TaskForms.SimpleWorkItem.Run()

===================================

The store schema does not contain the Element class SqlXmlCompressionOption. (Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql)

---

Program Location:

at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.SchemaModel.DataSchemaModel.ModelEntityFactory.CreateElement(String elementClassName, String nameString, Int32 line, Int32 column)
at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.SchemaModel.DataSchemaModel.PossibleElementState.ReadElement()
at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.SchemaModel.DataSchemaModel.ModelContentsState.ProcessStartElement()
at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.SchemaModel.XmlDeserializerEngine.ReadData(DeserializerState initialState, Boolean keepCurrentReaderPosition)
at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.SchemaModel.DataSchemaModel.DeserializeXml(TextReader input, ErrorManager errors, String source, Action`3 constructorParametersSetter) at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.SchemaModel.DataSchemaModel.DeserializePackage(SqlPackage package, ErrorManager errors, Action`3 constructorParametersSetter)
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DacPackage.DeserializePackage(SqlPackage package, DacSchemaModelStorageType modelStorageType, ErrorManager errorManager, DataSchemaModelHeader& header)
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DacPackage.LoadModel(IPackageSource packageSource, Boolean ignoreUnresolvedExternalErrors)

SQL on premise  Version (sql server 2019)

[image]

SQL Azure Version
[image]

Comment: try to install the dacfx latest version:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlpackage/sqlpackage-download?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Good morning, thank you very much for your help, but I downloaded the latest version of DAC Error continue
SqlPackage /Action:Import /SourceFile:"D:\AzureFiles\DatabaseClient-2022-07-31-10-11.bacpac" /TargetConnectionString:"Data Source=NB114;Initial Catalog=DatabaseClient; Integrated Security=true;"
Importing into database 'DatabaseClient' on server 'NB114'.
Creating deployment plan
Initializing deployment
*** Error when importing database: Error generating deployment plan. Deployment cannot continue.
The repository schema does not contain the Element SqlXmlCompressionOption class.

Comment: I noticed that the model.xml file generated by bacpac has more than 1000 tags in this format
<Element Type="SqlXmlCompressionOption" />
<Element Type="SqlXmlCompressionOption" />
  <Element Type="SqlXmlCompressionOption" />
  <Element Type="SqlXmlCompressionOption" />
  <Element Type="SqlXmlCompressionOption" />
  <Element Type="SqlXmlCompressionOption" />
<Element Type="SqlXmlCompressionOption" />
  <Element Type="SqlXmlCompressionOption" />
  <Element Type="SqlXmlCompressionOption" />
  <Element Type="SqlXmlCompressionOption" />
  <Element Type="SqlXmlCompressionOption" />

Comment: Are you using the latest version of SSMS?

Comment: Probably this XML compression is a new feature of Azure SQL Database...

Comment: @MBuschi , yes , my SSMS version is Last (19.2 preview)

SQL Server Management Studio      16.0.19056.0
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)    10.0.19041.1
Microsoft MSXML                             3.0 6.0 
Microsoft .NET Framework                       4.0.30319.42000
Operating System                                     10.0.19043

I need more information about this new compression feature, as I have already installed the latest version of DAC (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlpackage/sqlpackage-download?view=sql-server- ver16) and it doesn't give the same error.

Comment: probably the new feature is captured inside the dacpac but even the last dacfx version can't read it

Comment: maybe you can wipe out the xml element <Element Type="SqlXmlCompressionOption" /> you have found

Comment: @MBuschi
 the creation of the bacpack file is automated with this command that runs on a schedule in Automation Accounts powershell: $exportRequest = New-AzSqlDatabaseExport -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -ServerName $prdSqlServers.ServerName ` -DatabaseName $DatabaseCopy -StorageKeyType "StorageAccessKey" -StorageKey $StorageAccountKey -StorageUri $BacpacUri ` -AuthenticationType "Sql" -AdministratorLogin $CredLocalSQL.UserName -AdministratorLoginPassword $CredLocalSQL.Password

Answer (score 0):

the fix for this item has been released in SSMS 19 preview 3
available here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms-19?view=sql-server-ver16

follow the original thread
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73292856/the-store-schema-does-not-contain-the-element-class-sqlxmlcompressionoption/73332829#73332829